# KVM guest as default gateway for bridged network

Tags: kvm, route, forwarding, virt-manager

I currently have two vm's both on kvm (virt-manager), both running on separate virtual interfaces (`virbr0` and `virbr1`). The IP of `virbr0` is 192.168.122.0; the IP of `virbr1` is 192.168.123.0. Both VMs can talk to each other.

I am trying to make all traffic go through the VM on `virbr0` (122.0) before going to `virbr1` (123.0) from the host machine. Deleting the routing table for 123.0 and adding a new entry with the 122.0 VM as a gateway does not work, and the VMs lose connection after the route is deleted.

Any ideas how the traffic can be forwarded to 122.0 before hitting 123.0?

Comment: You need to put both VMs in the same subnet. In theory you can't route thought differents subnets. This can be done using NAT but isn't elegant. I would suggest to put both VMs under the same virtual interface and route from VM1 to VM2 and then to host machine as you wanted.